# Chrome won't print custom Google Map (that is inside a div)

Tags: google-chrome, printing

My Chrome version is 18.0.1025.142 m.

I used the JS API to make this [Google Map](https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocodingprint.html), but the map portion won't display in Chrome's Print Preview or actually print on paper.

Then I tried to [shrink the map](https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocodingprintsmall.html). Now, the contents clearly fit in one page, and show up in the print preview for IE, FF, and Opera. So size isn't the problem.

Do I have any unorthodox HTML or JS? Is there a way to rewrite the page (add the right CSS, maybe) so it will print in Chrome? Ignoring most of the JS, which is irrelevant here, this is what I wrote (the map_canvas div displays the map)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 67%; width: 30% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
...
 function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOptions);
...
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <b>address:</b>
      <input id="text_address" type="text" size="60" onkeyup="checkReturn(event)">
      <input id="check_sp" type="checkbox" checked="checked">SP
      <input type="button" value="clear" onclick="document.getElementById('text_address').value=''; document.getElementById('text_address').focus()">
      <input id="button3" type="button" value="clear markers" onclick="clearMarkers()">
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas">
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe swap the map element out for a static map image when printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems that the printing is working when the  fits the page. Thus, reduce it to the size that it would fit A4 page quite well and you're good :) Here you are:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:1000px;">
```